# How can I cancel one local notification in an app developed using Ionic, Capacitor and Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm developing an app using Ionic, Capacitor and Angular.

This project uses Local Notifications of Capacitor (https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/local-Notifications/)

I now how to cancel all the local notifications at the same time, but I need to cancel only one using its id but I don't know how to do it.

I have read the official documentation but I don't find how to do it. Can somebody help me?

Thank you,

Comment: I didn' t use capacitor local notifications before, but getPending() returns a promise so you could put then(notifications=>{ cancelNotification(notifications.id for example)}; here i mean you get the result of get pending and according to the results you could know the path of how to cancel a single push.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution. As said Mostafa I got all the pending notifications and then I have an array with all its ids.

With these ids and splice I can modify the array removing all the notifications that I don't want to delete and after that I cancel all the notifications of the array.

I leave here the method that I'm using in this case to delete all te notifcations except the notification con id 10000000.

```
LocalNotifications.getPending().then( res => {
      var index = res.notifications.map(x => {
        return x["id"];
      }).indexOf("10000000");
      res.notifications.splice(index, 1);
      LocalNotifications.cancel(res);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

*The solution provided by did not work for me*

After hours of spending trying to solve the same problem, I have managed to come up with simpler solution. Just create a new object of pending notifications to cancel.

```
const pending: LocalNotificationPendingList = {
  notifications: [
    {
      id: 'reminderId', // must be a string
    },
  ],
};

return LocalNotifications.cancel(pending);
```

Answer (score 1):

stumbled upon exactly the same issue.
I created a *workaround* by converting my unique **string guid**  to a **numeric** hash, which seems to work for my purpose now.

#### stringHashCode helper

Produces a ***persistent*** hashcode for a string

```
      // convert a string to hashcode (integer)
      private stringHashCode = (str) => {
         let hash = 0;
         for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
            hash = (Math.imul(31, hash) + str.charCodeAt(i)) | 0;
         }
         return hash;
      }
```

#### schedule + cancel logic

The notificationId is the unique database-key (session.id) converted to a numeric hashcode

```
      // make guid numeric
      const notificationId = this.stringHashCode(session.id);

      // schedule logic
      LocalNotifications.schedule({
          notifications: [{
                title: 'test',
                body: 'body content',
                id: notificationId, // <== numeric
                schedule: { at: moment().add(10, 'seconds').toDate() },
           }]
      });

     // cancel logic
     const notifications: LocalNotificationRequest[] = [{ id : `${notificationId}`}]; // <== string
     await LocalNotifications.cancel({notifications});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use the below function to cancel and clear a single notification from the list.**

```
 cancel_notification(){
    LocalNotifications.getPending().then( res => {
    res.notifications = res.notifications.filter(i => i.id == this.notificationId);
      if(res.notifications.length>0)
      LocalNotifications.cancel(res);
      else
     {
      console.log('notification length zero');
     }
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Your answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for the platform is ready and cancel all...

```
this.platform.ready().then()
{
   // Cancel All
   this.localNotifications.cancelAll();

   // Cancel by ID
   this.localNotifications.cancel(1);
}
```